# How To Create A New Gmail Contact Or A Yahoo Mail Contact From Android Device

Tags: contacts, gmail, contact-groups, yahoo-mail

I would like to create a new Gmail contact or Yahoo mail contact from my Android device.  It's a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2.  I've tried looking in the Yahoo mail app, the Gmail app, and the Google+ app on my phone, but I can't find any options to create a new contact.  I would prefer not to create the contact on my phone, since I've been having trouble exporting all of the device contact information to my Gmail and Yahoo mail accounts (specifically, it doesn't seem to send the groups that the contact is a member of).  Any help would be much appreciated, even if only to say that this is not possible or that it requires a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the default contacts app. When entering your new contact, there is an option where you can choose where it should be stored. Choose your Google account and you're all set.

[image]

Comment: This works for me.  However, on my phone, there doesn't seem to be an option to choose a Yahoo account...  Is there a reason for this?  If I go to settings and choose accounts, there is a Yahoo account listed on the phone, but it doesn't seem to show up when editing a contact...  Is Yahoo not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I know you can tap the icon next to their name in Gmail and it'll ask if you want them to added to your contact list, although not extensive, I'm sure can be edited further. I can't help with Yahoo!'s service though as I don't use them primarily. Someone else may be able to answer you on that point.